# Windows media foundation: Unplugging audio capture device returns wrong event

Tags: c#, audio, ms-media-foundation

I am using windows media foundation for keeping track of all the mics and cameras in an application. I am getting event type `MEError` instead of [`MECaptureAudioSessionDeviceRemoved`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162736(v=vs.85).aspx) when I unplug a Mic. I have tried unplugging Mics connected via USB and audio jack and I always get an eventtype with id `MEError`. The issue is not seen with video capture device(webcam) as I get the expected `MEVideoCaptureDeviceRemoved`event type.
The mic's are getting initialized correctly as I can hear the audio correctly.

I have found zero information on this particular(unplugging mic with media foundation) issue on the internets. On top of this, I am a newbie C# dev. I am curious to understand why I am not getting the `MECaptureAudioSessionDeviceRemoved` but getting the `MEError`? Is this something the Mic driver developer did not implement or is it something expected if an error exists in my code?

Here's my code for getting the EventType(Not exactly necessary for my question) The class this function belongs to implements `IMFAsyncCallback`-

```
HRESULT MicCaptureSession::Invoke(IMFAsyncResult* pAsyncResult)
{
    ComPointerCustom<IMFMediaEvent> pEvent;

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_critSec);

    if (pAsyncResult == 0)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    hr = m_localSession->EndGetEvent(pAsyncResult, &pEvent);

    MediaEventType eventType;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HRESULT hrStatus = S_OK;

    UINT32 TopoStatus = MF_TOPOSTATUS_INVALID;

    if (pEvent== NULL)
        return E_UNEXPECTED;

    hr = pEvent->GetType(&eventType);   <------ Y U NO WORK ??

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }

    hr = pEvent->GetStatus(&hrStatus);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }
    /* ----- MORE CODE -----*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say exactly reason of it, but I can advice you check more error invokes. Audio capture is different from video capture - video capture usually has about 33 ms between frames, but audio capture has about 5 - 10 ms, and it can generate MEError before then Windows Audio driver generate MECaptureAudioSessionDeviceRemoved.
Also, usually MF sources generate chain of errors. Try to check more error invokes from audio capture source.

Comment: Good point and I checked for this. There is only one invoke that happens and that is of type MEError. There is no more event invokes after this. Same on webcam unplug, only one event and that is of type EVideoCaptureDeviceRemoved.

Comment: It is unusual question. I have some experience with MF and capturing video and audio on it: [Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/776058/Capturing-Live-video-from-Web-camera-on-Windows-an), [CaptureManager-SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1017223/CaptureManager-SDK). From MSDN - MECaptureAudioSessionDeviceRemoved event
Sent by an audio capture source when the device is removed. It means that this event must be sent by Source, but in the code you try to catch it by MicCaptureSession from session. What session?

Comment: Another good point. Each of my Mic device is of type [IMFMediaEventGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701755%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and I hook up MicCaptureSession(implements IMFAsyncCallback) to the device using this [BeginGetEvent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Thanks for helping out. Dealing with code not written by me.